# Laravel 5.3 throws error formrequest

Tags: php, request, laravel-5.3

I've made a `request` class in `Laravel 5.3`. Looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'              => 'required|max:25|min:2'
        ];
    }
}
```

But when I use that in my controller I receive:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

When I remove the rules so it looks like this:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [

   ];
}
```

It suddenly works !?!?

--UPDATE--

It looks like the validator looks in my `web.php` but I don't have a route there (that's why I receive the exception: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`).  I didn't have this problem in `5.2`. What should I do?

--UPDATE--

**My current routes:**

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                                           | Name         | Action                                            | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST      | api/login                                     |              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login    | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/register/{user}/verify/{ConformationCode} |              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminController@confirm | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                                      | user.index   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@index    | api,active |
|        | POST      | api/user                                      | user.store   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@store    | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/create                               | user.create  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@create   | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/{user}                               | user.show    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@show     | api,active |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/user/{user}                               | user.update  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@update   | api,active |
|        | DELETE    | api/user/{user}                               | user.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@destroy  | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/{user}/edit                          | user.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@edit     | api,active
```

Also if try this with a fresh `Laravel 5.3` install I receive the error!

**Perhaps it has something to do with:**

in `Laravel 5.3` `UserStoreRequest`

`extends FormRequest`
`(use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;)`

And in `Laravel 5.2` `UserStoreRequest`

`extends Request`
`(use App\Http\Requests\Request;)`

--EDIT--

**API.PHP**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/


Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('/register/{user}/verify/{ConformationCode}', 'Auth\AdminController@confirm');
Route::put('/test', 'User\UserController@test');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['active']], function () {
    Route::resource('user',         'User\UserController');
    Route::resource('corporation',  'Corporation\CorporationController');
    Route::resource('forum',        'Forum\ForumController');
    Route::resource('topic',        'Topic\TopicController');
});
```

**Store method**

```
 public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        if($this->authorize($this->user))
        {
            $user = $this->userInfo->store($request);
            event(new UserRegistered($user));

            return response()->json(['success' => 'gebruiker succesvol aangemaakt. Welkom email verzonden.']);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'niet geautoriseerd'], 401);
    }
```

Comment: Please show your `routes/api.php` and `UserController` `store` method

Comment: @Alejandro please see my last edit!

Comment: Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `FormRequest::response` function wants to redirect you to a page with the errors. But because you don't have any web routes (only api routes), it will fail with a `NotFoundHttpException`. If you had any web routes, it would have (internally) redirected you to the root.

If you look inside of that [`FormRequest::response`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L145) function, you can see this bit:

```
if($this->expectsJson()) {
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
}
```

So if you can fullfill the expections in `expectsJson`, it works as expected.

**You can do this in a couple of ways:**

- Make sure the request is an XMLHttpRequest by supplying the `X-Requested-With`header.
- Supply a [X-PJAX](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1366737736-What-is-pjax-and-why-we-should-use-it) header
- Supply a `Accept` header with `application/json`
- Overwrite the `wantsJson` call on the request to always return true. Like so:

`class JsonRequest extends Request
{
    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }
}`

Comment: Finally an answer that works! Thanks. In the example that you gave I guess the ```extends Request``` should be ```extends FormRequest``` (changed in Laravel 5.3). Very strange that I did not find this in the documentation.